# Can't transform a Source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource Camel-Springws

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-ws

Facing this issue occasionally when the war gets deployed in server. Issue gets resolved on restarting. Sometimes multiple restarts are required to resolve the issue.

I've used the following bean configuration in my context

```
<bean id="baseCamelMarshallerWSTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
    <property name="transformerFactoryClass" value="com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
</bean>
```

I've added the baseCamelMarshallerWSTemplate to the springws endpoint configuration as follows :

```
from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://example.com/}GetFoo?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping&webServiceTemplate=baseCamelMarshallerWSTemplate")
```

But the issue seems to occur. It is not possible to set the transformer factory to com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl as a java system property in server due to restrictions.

Please provide any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel-Springws provides an option to specify transformer factory directly and it solved the issue.

In your bean configuration file, specify the transformer factory class to be used

```
<bean id="transformerFactory" class="com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
```

Add the transformerFactory to Springws endpoint configuration as follows :

```
spring-ws:rootqname:{http://services.com/ServiceV1.0}Request?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping&transformerFactory=#transformerFactory
```